# Gravity Forms List Field Read Only column

Tags: gravity, gravityforms

Would anyone happen to know how to set readonly in a cell/column of gravity forms list field? I need one column for input and the others should not be edited by the user.

Gravity Perks has confirmed the list column is not supported by their plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Add the  following to an HTML field on your form:
**

```
You will need to know the list field id and the column you want to make read-only.  If your list field is 32 for instance and you want the second column to be "read-only", you would replace the second line below with .gfield_list_32_cell2

<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery( '.gfield_list_1_cell1' ).find( 'input, select, textarea' ).each(
      function() {
         if ( jQuery( this ).val() != '' ) {
          jQuery( this ).prop( 'readonly', true );
        }
      });
  });

</script>
```